# Is it possible to reconstruct a String in Java more efficently?

Tags: java

I am breaking a string which might have 5 to 8 tokens.

```
String [] tweet = line.split(",");
String input =tweet[1];
```

I want to cleverly make changes to `input` and then simply replace it with another processed string, while everything in the `tweet` array remains the same. I can do a hardcode by forming a string like:

```
tweet[0]+","+stop_word_less_tweet+","+tweet[2]+","+tweet[3]+ and so on..
```

But I am sure there is a better way.

---

I am splitting a line of a tweet, which might have 5-8 tokens, depending on it's hashtags extracted. I remove stop words from the tweet text itself, at tweet[1]. Now, I want to be able to re-construct the entire tweet line with the newly built stop_word_less_tweet so it's together.

Comment: Do you mean efficient in speed of execution or easy of programming/clarity?

Comment: Let me rephrase it. I am splitting a line of a tweet, which might have 5-8 tokens, depending on it's hashtags extracted. I remove stop words from the tweet text itself, at tweet[1]. Now, I want to be able to re-construct the entire tweet line with the newly built stop_word_less_tweet so it's together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to change only content of `tweet[1]` then you don't have to split your text into 5-8 tokens. Use `split` with limit to split it at 3 elements where

- first element will contain first token
- second element will contain second token (with word you want to remove)
- third element will contain rest of tokens like `token3,token4,...`

Try with

```
String [] tweet = line.split(",", 3);//
String stop_word_less_tweet = change(tweet[1]);

String result = tweet[0] + "," + stop_word_less_tweet + "," + tweet[2];
```

This way `result` will always be created from 3 elements so you will not have to worry about dynamically adding these `5-8` tokens. Just concatenate:

- `tweet[0]`
- `stop_word_less_tweet`
- and `tweet[2]`

and Java compiler will compile it using `StringBuilder` for you as

```
String result = new StringBuilder(tweet[0])
                .append(",")
                .append(stop_word_less_tweet)
                .append(",")
                .append(tweet[2])
                .toString();
```

so you shouldn't have problems with performance.

Comment: @AliGajani: *I want to cleverly make changes to input*. change() is the method that would make these clever changes.

Comment: Yes, I got it. I was already doing that, just (",",3) did it for me.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the StringBuffer and the StringBuilder classes (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html). They are way more efficient when handling strings. You can search for the input in question and replace it with the `replace` method.

Answer (score 1):

Use this for efficiency and readability purposes:

```
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
buffer.append("hello, ");
buffer.append("world");
String output = buffer.toString();
```

In your case:

```
String[] tweets = line.split(",");
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
for (String tweet : tweets) buffer.append(tweet);
System.out.println(buffer.toString());
```

Useful resources:

**[This blog](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/)**

Comment: My string might have multiple tokens, as I said, 5 to 8. How do I work that out, surely there has to be a nicer way.

Comment: Note that StringBuilder is better if you don't need it to be synchronized. Though, as your link says, newer JVMs can handle all of it.

Comment: I don't think stringbuilder is more  readable than plain concatenation.

Comment: @AliGajani then just loop through the tokens and append them to the String Buffer

Comment: martynas, that's what I am asking, hence the question :)

Comment: @AliGajani updated the answer. Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

For performance use StringBuilder. But only try that if measurements suggest you have a problem as the compiler will actually use it for you most of the time anyway and it makes your code harder to read.

For better programming create a function that takes your array and the element to place on position one. Implement it with a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

use StringBuilder if its single thread application

```
String [] tweets = line.split(",");
StringBuilder builder= new StringBuilder();
for (String tweet : tweets) builder.append(tweet);
System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

String builder is more fast and prefarable than string buffer if its single threaded application

if multithread go ahead with stringbuffer

Comment: Every application is a multi-thread application. Being single-thread or multi-thread is not what matters. What matters is if several threads use the same StringBuilder. And in 16 years of Java programming, I've never encountered such a situation.